# Translation tool for Android to assist in providing context

Tags: android, translation, android-xml, android-resources

Does anyone know of any tools that can assist translators with translating string resources? That can help provide the context in which the strings exist?

We normally send the [string resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) out for translation and often get questioned about the context of the strings. Such a tool would greatly mitigate these questions whilst also proving invaluable providing captures of strings in the application to validate that they have been translated correctly.

So to summarize, is there a tool that can:

- Capture screenshots of activities, notifications, etc
- Switch languages

So far I haven't found anything and am considering using robotium to automate things, however if something already exists I would rather use that.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a perfect solution, but we add comments to our string resources that include

- A brief explanation of the context
- The type of UI element
- The max length for the resource

e.g.

```
 <!-- This is displayed on the app preferences screen. -->
 <!-- Label [25] -->
 <string name="preferences_server_name">Server Name</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

if you have a 4.0 > devices you just click the screen shot directly on them (varies from device to device, but on nexus for example is power+vol.down).

other way that exists since 1.0 is through the Eclipse plugin. Find the 'Devices' view on it, select the device that is running your app and there's a camera button on the top-right that takes screen shots and bring them directly to your PC.

Comment: I'm aware I can do this manually via `ddms` but was wondering these is a tool that can automate this? It'll be some what time consuming to do this for 25 different languages.

Comment: but wouldn't be correct to assume that the translation company will translate from one language (e.g. english) to 25 others. So you should only supply them one set of screen-shots. Apart from that I don't believe there're any other tools, sorry.

Comment: That's true. I was hoping something would exist that could automate this so to provide them with screenshots with their translations in so that they can be verified that the translations are correct. Thanks for your advice though :)